# Not the squares you were looking for

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

- A $5\times5$ square has area $\pi$.
- A $7\times7$ square has area $8$.
- An $8\times8$ square has area $0$.
- A $10\times10$ square has area $30$ (not quite $13$).

**Why?**

The answer should be clear when you find it, and does not involve arbitrary or tenuous connections.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Can get by

> Converting the letters to the answers into the alphabetic equivalent
> pi 16+9 = 25 = 5x5
> eight  5+9+7+8+20 = 49 = 7x7
> zero   26+5+18+15 = 64 = 8x8
> thirty  20+8+9+18+20+25 = 100 = 10x10
> (thirteen 20+8+9+18+20+5+5+14 = 99 = nearly 100)

Comment: Excellent! Well spotted.

Comment: .   Good puzzle!   .

Comment: Funny story: this was almost a [tag:reverse-puzzling] challenge. I have a text file that I use for making notes while trying to solve various puzzles; today I was clearing up some obsolete stuff from now-fully-solved puzzles, and I found something rot13(nqqvat gur yrggref va MREB naq CV gb trg fvkgl-sbhe naq gjragl-svir). Even now I don't remember why I wrote that there or what I was trying to solve then, but I noticed the squares and thought, hey, that'd make a fun new puzzle!